# Pentaho error-Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, pentaho

While using an SQL select query in a table input step in pentaho DI CE version 4.3, though following error pops up:

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

On rechecking, both the username and password are correct. All connection details like host name, database name, port, etc. are also set correct. The database to be connected to is an Oracle 10g via native access (JDBC). The drivers are also matching, but this error still arises randomly. Sometimes it does, sometimes not. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything in PDI's log file?

Comment: can you run it with Rowlevel logging?

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. I have found out the error. It seems it was a small error arising due to the jobs I have developed. It was receiving the credential fields as null value so it says invalid username/password